# New interface remains in editing mode after posting an edited message

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web

I'm using the new chat interface, which works great.

However, there's a minor bug when editing a message. Pressing `Enter` should post the message, which it does. But the screen remains in editing mode, as can be seen by the top bar and the icon next to the input box.

[image: a screenshot showing the effect]

This is using Opera on Android. More info / different browsers available when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fixed now. I decided pretty late to allow "submit via enter" in the new mobile client, and the code that ends editing mode just responded to the click on the submit button. This is fixed now – anything that ends editing, no matter what particular thing you click, will also end the mobile UI's editing mode.

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a specific tag I should use for questions about the new mobile interface?

Comment: The ones you used where correct -- [meta-tag:chat] combined with [meta-tag:mobile-web]. I just removed [meta-tag:opera] because this wasn't a browser-specific issue.